# If $A$ is an open subset of a separable space $(X,\mathscr{T}),$ then $(A,\mathscr{T}_{A})$ is separable.

Tags: general-topology

I know that $(X,\mathscr{T})$ being separable means that there is some set $B$ which is countable and dense, i.e. $\overline{B} = X.$ Now, this means that $B$ has a nonempty intersection with every open set in $\mathscr{T}.$ In fact, $\mathscr{T}$ must have countably many disjoint open sets otherwise it would contradict that $B$ is countable. With that in mind, I considered all $U_{n}\in\mathscr{T}$ such that $b_{n}\in U_{n}$ and $b_{n}\in A.$ Then it would follow that
\begin{equation*}
b_{n} \in A\cap U_{n} = V_{n}\in\mathscr{T}_{A}
\end{equation*}
So if we considered the set $C = \{b_{n}\in V_{n}\ | \ V_{n}\in\mathscr{T}_{A}\},$ then $C$ is clearly countable and I figured I can show that $\mathrm{cl}_{A}(C) = A.$ To this end, I know that $\mathrm{cl}_{A}(C) = A\cap \mathrm{cl}_{X}(C)$ and that $\mathrm{cl}_{X}(C) = C \cup C'$ where $C'$ denotes the limit points of $C.$ Well it's trivial that $C\subseteq A,$ so I figured all I had to show was that $C'\subseteq A$ so that way $A\cap\mathrm{cl}_{X}(C) = A$ and I would have my result.

I have a couple of questions. The first of which is if my train of thought is sound. Are there any things I took for granted, or is it all legitimate to the very end where I am stuck? Secondly, where do I go from here? I'm having difficulty showing the limit points are indeed a subset. And of course, if there is a better way to do this, I gladly welcome it and appreciate any advice at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $B$ is dense in $(X,\mathscr T)$ and $A\in\mathscr T$ then $B\cap A$ is dense in $(A,\mathscr T_A)$.

Proof:

Let $U\subseteq A$ be open in $A$ and non-empty.

Then $U=V\cap A$ for some $V\in\mathscr T$.

Also $A\in\mathscr T$ so we have $U\in\mathscr T$.

Consequence is that $U\cap B\neq\varnothing$, because $B$ is dense in $X$.

Here $U\cap B=U\cap (B\cap A)$ because $U$ is a subset of $A$.

Final conclusion: $U\cap (B\cap A)\neq\varnothing$.

Comment: Okay, so then because $U\cap A = U,$ viewing $U\cap B$ as $U\cap (B\cap A)$ would imply that $B\cap A$ has a nonempty intersection with every $U\in\mathscr{T}_{A}?$ Which means $A\cap B$ is necessarily dense, correct?

Comment: Indeed. Also the countability of $B$ implies the countability of $B\cap A$.